# Error when making class protected

Tags: java

I am getting the error "Remove invalid modifier" when I use the `protected` keyword on class Zoo.

```
protected class Zoo {
   int  x=5;
 String  coolMethod() {
return "Wow baby";
}

 static Test t=new Test();
}
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test zoo=new Test();
    //System.out.println(zoo.coolMethod()); 
    //System.out.println(x);

    //t.useMyCoolMethod();
    //Testing v=new Testing();
    //System.out.println(v.getValue());
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `protected` modifier is only valid in inner or nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

Top level (non-inner) classes can't be `protected`, only `public`, or package (default) access.

Answer (score 0):

Classes can only be public. Inner classes can be protected